# Given the set $S_n = \{0, 1 \dots n-1\}$. Prove that you can get every subset of $S_n$ starting from $S_n$ and using only two given operations.

Tags: combinatorics, automata

So it's given this set.
$$S_n = \{0, 1 \dots n-1 \}$$
We have two operations $Add : P(2^{S_n}) \rightarrow P(2^{S_n})$ and  $RemoveZero: P(2^{S_n}) \rightarrow P(2^{S_n})$:
$$Add(\{x_1 \dots x_k\}) = \{ x_1 + 1 \mod n , \space \space x_2 +1 \mod n, \space \space \space \dots  \space \space x_k+1 \mod n\}$$
$$RemoveZero(S) = S \setminus{\{0\}}$$

I need to show that it's possible to get every subset of $S_n$ starting from $S_n$ and using only there two operations.

I was trying to show it by induction. It's easy to see that $(Add\circ RemoveZero )^k(S_n))$ gives an set with n-k elements. So I can get a set of every size. But I can't continue. Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S_n$ be as given and let $S$ be a subset of $S_n$.

We will show that the following algorithm gives us $S$.

for $i$ going from $n-1$ to $0$
$\\\\\ \ \ \ \text{Add}(S_n)$
$\\\\\ \ \ \ \text{if }i\not\in (S)\  \text{RemoveZero}(S_n)$

We go through the loop $n$ times. If an element $k$ doesn't get removed then its final value is $k+n\ \text{mod}\ n=k$ because we add $1$ to every element before evaluating whether or not to remove the zero.

Comment: In hindsight, this algorithm works going from $0$ to $n-1$ as well. I wrote it this way because this is what occurred to me first.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you are sitting at a circular table with $n$ place settings, each of which has a cupcake (numbered $0$ to $n-1$). You can perform one of these two actions as many times as you like:

- Eat the cupcake in front of you.
- Rotate the table one spot clockwise.

Do you see how, for any subset $S$ of cupcakes, it is possible to eat all of the cupcakes outside of $S$ and none of the cupcakes in $S$, using those operations alone? And can you see how this is the same as the problem you asked?

---

Comment: yes, but it's the formal proof that I can't do. intuitively I understand it.

Comment: @PaulKeseru First, describe in English how to solve the cupcake problem. Then, translate that back into to the set language (rotate -> add, eat cupcake -> remove-zero). A description of an algorithm to get any set counts as a proof.